# Invalid object name 'Web1'.(Web1 is a sql Database name)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

throw ex;(While compiling the error displayed "Invalid Object Name"Web1"" can you help me where i put mistake and i am beginner too so give ideas how to learn C# .net,Sql server.

```
   public int insertweb(Com_web cw)
  {
      int result=0;
      try
      SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("saveweb",con);
      cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empid",SqlDbType.Int).Value=cw.Empid;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empname",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=cw.Empname;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empphonenumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value=cw.Empphonenumber;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empemailid",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=cw.Empemailid;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      result=1;
      return result;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }

     }
    }
   }
  USE [Web1]-----Web1 is a Database name.
  GO
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[saveweb]
  @Empid int,
  @Empname varchar(50),
  @Empphonenumber int,
  @Empemailid varchar(50)
  as
  begin
  insert Webtable(Empid,Empname,Empphonenumber,Empemailid)
  values (@Empid,@Empname,@Empphonenumber,@Empemailid)
  end
```

Comment: Well, the only presence of `Web1` in your question are in references to the error message. Since you're not showing us any *code* that includes the reference to `Web1`, we're unlikely to be able to spot the issue.

Comment: `insert Web1(...` should presumably be `insert SomeTableName(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether `web1` database is available or not.and your insert query seems wrong, you are missing `into` in the insert query

```
insert into Webtable(Empid,Empname,Empphonenumber,Empemailid)
  values (@Empid,@Empname,@Empphonenumber,@Empemailid)
```

---

use this to find all databases

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

---

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: @rakulrc have you got output??

Comment: i m missing some query..i  got the answer.

Comment: while i come to chat room i cannot msg u give your gmail id i come to gtalk, i have a question about console app....